# Bad formatting on Avatar when viewing profile

Tags: bug, profile-picture

It looks like for whatever reason, [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875317/b-clay-shannon)'s avatar gets cutoff when browsing with Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 on Windows 10:

[image]

When using Microsoft Edge, the frame around the avatar looks correct, but for whatever reason its slimmer than other profiles.

It happens to [every profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/52820/b-clay-shannon) [they have](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/2111/b-clay-shannon) [on the network](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/2573/b-clay-shannon), so I'm guessing it's an issue with their description?

Is this a bug?